# How to show that $\int \lambda((A-x)\cap B) \, d\lambda = \lambda(A)\lambda(B)$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given measurable sets $A, B\subset\mathbb R$, how can we show that
$$\int_\mathbb R \lambda((A-x)\cap B) \, d\lambda = \lambda(A)\lambda(B)$$
holds?

I don't see how the integrand might be simplified. The Lebesgue-measure is invariant under translation, so it would be sufficient to show that $\lambda((A-x)\cap B)=\lambda(A-x) \chi_B$ somehow, but I don't know how that might be argued.

Is there an argument that allows that transformation? Or is there a better way entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has $\lambda((A-x)\cap B) = \int 1_{(A-x) \cap B}(y) \,d\lambda(y)$ so that

\begin{align}
& \int \lambda((A-x)\cap B)\,d\lambda(x) \\[6pt]
= {} & \iint 1_{(A-x) \cap B}(y) \,d\lambda(y)\,d\lambda(x) \\[6pt]
= {} & \iint 1_{y \in (A-x) \cap B} \,d\lambda(y)\,d\lambda(x) \\[6pt]
= {} & \iint 1_{y \in B}1_{x  \in (A-y)} \,d\lambda(y)\,d\lambda(x) \\[6pt]
= {} & \iint 1_{y \in B}1_{x  \in (A-y)} \,d\lambda(x)\,d\lambda(y) \\[6pt]
= {} & \int 1_{y \in B}\lambda(A-y)\,d\lambda(y) \\[6pt]
= {} & \lambda(A)\int 1_{y \in B}\,d\lambda(y) \\[6pt]
= {} & \lambda(A)\lambda(B).
\end{align}